# Failed to %AddDeps HBase 1.3.1 from Jupyter-Toree-Scala

Tags: scala, hbase, jupyter, apache-toree

I'm using this jupyter toree notebook in a docker container (https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook).

I tried to add HBASE dependency with this %AddDeps command in the notebook:

`%AddDeps org.apache.hbase hbase 1.3.1 --transitive --verbose`

All dependencies seem to be found, yet I still get this output (null error?):

```
Magic AddDeps failed to execute with error: 
null
```

I can't call `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase` subsequently, meaning that the library isn't installed yet. I'd really appreciate any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. Imported the wrong project-name. Should've been `%AddDeps org.apache.hbase hbase-client 1.2.0 --transitive`